2006 Pontiac Torrent. Steering column shaking just over 60 mph
New ball joints. After that brake caliper was hanging up keeping the brakes engaged - new brakes, including caliper and rotor.  After that new tires and alignment.  Car tracks straight with no pulling to either side.  At just over 60 mph steering wheel starts to rattle and shake.  When I let off the gas (not applying brakes) the shaking worsens until speed is below 60 mph.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Hi! Hope you can help.

Steering wheel shakes and steering column rattles.

Take the car back to where you got the tires installed and have them re-balance your tires/wheels. What you're describing is indicative of an out of balance issue. Because they are new tires, they should re-balance for free. Just tell them what's going on and it feels like the tire is out of balance.

Will do. Thank you for your assistance. Will let you know if that fixes the problem.
